# subset all rows with the same value in one column, grouped by another column, where at least one row of third column contains a specific letter in R

Tags: r

I am gathering data from a database, where I have two different ID identifiers (ID1, Nr). I want to collect all the rows, that have duplicated ID1, grouped by "Nr", WHERE at least one record in Names has a letter "a".

```
df <- data_frame(ID1 = c('100', '100', '100', '100', '100', '100', '100', '100', '100'),
                 Nr = c('1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '3', '4'),
                 Names = c('aaa bb', 'aa bbb', 'ccc', 'ccc', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'ccc', 'ccc', 'add'))
```

So, the desired output would be:

```
output <- data_frame(ID1= c('100', '100', '100', '100'),
                     Nr = c('1', '1', '1', '4'),
                     Names = c('aaa bb', 'aa bbb', 'ccc', 'add'))
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `group_by` `Nr` column and use `grepl` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Nr) %>% filter(any(grepl('a', Names)))

#  ID1   Nr    Names 
# <chr> <chr> <chr> 
#1 100   1     aaa bb
#2 100   1     aa bbb
#3 100   1     ccc   
#4 100   4     add
```

The same logic can be implemented in base R

```
subset(df, ave(grepl('a', Names), Nr, FUN = any))
```

as well as `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[any(grepl('a', Names))], Nr]
```

In the orignal dataset if you have more `ID`'s you might want to include it in `group_by` as well.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed.